# Why does ARC autorelease when using weak references?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Why can't ARC use a regular release?

Example:

```
[weakObject doSomething];
```

From what I understand, ARC turns this into:

```
Object *strongObject = objc_autorelease(objc_loadWeakRetained(weakObject));
[strongObject doSomething];
```

Why doesn't ARC do this instead?:

```
Object *strongObject = objc_loadWeakRetained(weakObject);
[strongObject doSomething];
objc_release(strongObject);
```

I'd like to do away with as many autoreleases in ARC as possible. I do a lot of async threading with GCD and I end up having to add autorelease pools a lot:

```
dispatch_async(self.myQueue, ^{
    @autoreleasepool{
        [weakObject doSomethingBig];
    }
});
```

Comment: Lack of a sufficiently smart compiler, basically. Might be worth a bug report, though it's likely been filed and is definitely known.

Comment: Where do you get weakObject from?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot explain why the ARC compiler does it this way, but
if I understand the generated assembly code correctly, using the following pattern

```
dispatch_async(self.myQueue, ^{
    Object *strongObject = weakObject;
    [strongObject doSomething];
});
```

is translated into `objc_loadWeakRetained()`, ..., `objc_release()`, so that the object
is not put into an autorelease pool.