# ARC blocks, weak and retain count

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, block

I thought that I had quite understood weak references and blocks, however when trying the below code snippets, there are a few things that I don't understand.

Method **test1**: all fine the object is not retained

Method **test2**: I don't understand why the object seems to get retained until the end of method **test3**! Even explicitly setting `object = nil` at the end of method **test2** does not change anything.

Method **test3**: the object is not retained. Why is method **test2** not behaving like this?

As a side question, I was actually wondering if weak variables are thread safe? ie if I will never get any BAD_ACCESS exception when trying to access a weak variable from different threads.

```
@interface Object : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger index;
@end

@implementation Object

- (id)initWithIndex:(NSInteger) index {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _index = index;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"Deallocating object %d", _index);
}

@end
```

Test methods

```
- (void) test1 {
    NSLog(@"test1");
    Object* object = [[Object alloc] initWithIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"Object: %@", object);
    __weak Object* weakObject = object;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create(NULL, NULL), ^{
        //NSLog(@"Weak object: %@", weakObject);
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
        NSLog(@"Exiting dispatch");
    });
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    NSLog(@"Exiting method");
}

- (void) test2 {
    NSLog(@"test2");
    Object* object = [[Object alloc] initWithIndex:2];
    NSLog(@"Object: %@", object);
    __weak Object* weakObject = object;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create(NULL, NULL), ^{
        NSLog(@"Weak object: %@", weakObject);
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
        NSLog(@"Exiting dispatch");
    });
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    NSLog(@"Exiting method");
}

- (void) test3 {
    NSLog(@"test3");
    Object* object = [[Object alloc] initWithIndex:3];
    NSLog(@"Object: %@", object);
    NSValue *weakObject = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:object];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create(NULL, NULL), ^{
        NSLog(@"Weak object: %@", [weakObject nonretainedObjectValue]);
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
        NSLog(@"Exiting dispatch");
    });
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    NSLog(@"Exiting method");
}

- (void) test {
    [self test1];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
    [self test2];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
    [self test3];
}
```

The output of the above is:

```
2013-05-11 19:09:56.753 test[1628:c07] test1
2013-05-11 19:09:56.754 test[1628:c07] Object: <Object: 0x7565940>
2013-05-11 19:09:57.755 test[1628:c07] Exiting method
2013-05-11 19:09:57.756 test[1628:c07] Deallocating object 1
2013-05-11 19:09:58.759 test[1628:1503] Exiting dispatch
2013-05-11 19:10:00.758 test[1628:c07] test2
2013-05-11 19:10:00.758 test[1628:c07] Object: <Object: 0x71c8260>
2013-05-11 19:10:00.759 test[1628:1503] Weak object: <Object: 0x71c8260>
2013-05-11 19:10:01.760 test[1628:c07] Exiting method
2013-05-11 19:10:02.760 test[1628:1503] Exiting dispatch
2013-05-11 19:10:04.761 test[1628:c07] test3
2013-05-11 19:10:04.762 test[1628:c07] Object: <Object: 0x71825f0>
2013-05-11 19:10:04.763 test[1628:1503] Weak object: <Object: 0x71825f0>
2013-05-11 19:10:05.764 test[1628:c07] Exiting method
2013-05-11 19:10:05.764 test[1628:c07] Deallocating object 3
2013-05-11 19:10:05.767 test[1628:c07] Deallocating object 2
2013-05-11 19:10:06.764 test[1628:1503] Exiting dispatch
```

Comment: Well clearly the NSLog statement makes all the difference between test 1 and test 2! (Because it mentions `weakObject`, bringing it into the block.)

Comment: I get that, however weakObject is a __weak local variable so shouldn't it not increase the retain count? Or does it get copied over as a strong variable when it is accessed inside the block?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11603363/341994 for one part of your q.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn’t my weak reference cleared right after the strong ones are gone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266367/why-isnt-my-weak-reference-cleared-right-after-the-strong-ones-are-gone) - Summary: *Accessing* the weak pointer retains+autoreleases the object.

Comment: Compare also: [Why variable with __weak qualifier and __bridge cast retains an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494996/why-variable-with-weak-qualifier-and-bridge-cast-retains-an-object)

Comment: @Martin R, Ok from your two links I get that NSLog is actually retaining and autoreleasing the object under the hood. However, it I add a square method to the object and replace the NSLog line in method test2 by int square = [weakObject square:2];, the object still does not get deallocated before end of test3.

Comment: @goldmine: `square = [weakObject square:2];` also accesses `weakObject`, so the compiler also generates a `objc_loadWeak()` call that retains+autoreleases the object. - So this is not a NSLog() feature but a general issue about accesses to weak objects. - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493076/why-does-arc-autorelease-when-using-weak-references for another variation on the topic.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all those references. Still trying to get my head around it. Btw, why is test3 behaving differently than test2, ie why is the object not retained in test3?

Comment: @goldmine: Because `valueWithNonretainedObject:` stores a `__unsafe_unretained` pointer, not a `__weak` pointer.

Comment: Note that the behavior will likely change depending on whether the optimizer is enabled.

Comment: @bbum: Actually the behavior of "test2" is identical in Debug and Release build, a `objc_loadWeak()` call for accessing `weakObject` is created in both cases.

Comment: @MartinR Sure -- which may also be an implementation detail.  The compiler's behavior will change over time as long as the resulting code fills the "behaves correctly and coherently" requirement.

Comment: In particular, it seems likely that it will eventually be able to emit objc_loadWeakRetained() + objc_release() pairs instead of many objc_loadWeak() calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two observations on your three tests before I touch on a few of your questions:

1. Your testing is complicated by the fact that you're running all three tests in a row, not yielding back to the run loop, and thus your autorelease pool is not getting flushed (so it making things look like they're persisting longer than they normally would). You should do you testing, one test at a time, to really understand what's going on. It's not good if you're drawing conclusions about the lifespan of some object, whereas you really may just be experiencing some artifact of the fact that you're not letting the autorelease pool from being flushed.
2. You are doing all of these tests as `dispatch_async`, which starts the dispatched block very quickly, sometimes more quickly than it takes the underlying object to fall out of scope and you're often accessing the `weakObject` as one of the first steps in the dispatched block. I'd suggest using `dispatch_after` (so you're really giving the calling method a chance to let the variables fall out of scope), so you'll better see what's going on.

Your tests are a good data point, but I think it's useful to also test the same stuff using `dispatch_after` and do one test at a time with fewer of those `sleepForTimeInterval`. It feels like some of the idiosyncrasies of your tests are counterfeiting some key behavior.

Anyway you ask:

> Method test2: I don't understand why the object seems to get retained until the end of method test3! Even explicitly setting object = nil at the end of method test2 does not change anything.

It's undoubtedly fallen into the autorelease pool, which won't be drained until the `test` method is done.

To my prior points, try doing `test2` again, but have the operation wait two seconds before accessing the `weakObject` (or get rid of all of these `sleepForTimeInterval` statements and use `dispatch_after` instead of `dispatch_sync`):

```
- (void) test2 {
    NSLog(@"test2");
    Object* object = [[Object alloc] initWithIndex:2];
    NSLog(@"Object: %@", object);
    __weak Object* weakObject = object;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create(NULL, NULL), ^{
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];      // new sleep
        NSLog(@"Weak object: %@", weakObject);
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
        NSLog(@"Exiting dispatch");
    });
    // [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];       // not really necessary
    NSLog(@"Exiting method");
}
```

You'll see that this behaves more like you expected.

> Method test3: the object is not retained. Why is method test2 not behaving like this?

Needless to say, your `test3` is seriously bad news, easily crashing itself. For example, try commenting out the sleep line:

```
- (void) test3 {
    NSLog(@"test3");
    Object* object = [[Object alloc] initWithIndex:3];
    NSLog(@"Object: %@", object);
    NSValue *weakObject = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:object];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create(NULL, NULL), ^{
        NSLog(@"Weak object: %@", [weakObject nonretainedObjectValue]);
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
        NSLog(@"Exiting dispatch");
    });
//    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    NSLog(@"Exiting method");
}
```

It strikes me that it's behaving less like `weak` and more like `unsafe_unretained`.

> As a side question, I was actually wondering if weak variables are thread safe? ie if I will never get any BAD_ACCESS exception when trying to access a weak variable from different threads.

You can get exceptions in a lot of ways. If you pass `weakObject` to some method that requires that it not be `nil` (e.g. `NSMutableArray` method `addObject`), you'll get an exception. You can also get exceptions if you dereference ivars for a `nil` object pointer, e.g. `obj->objectIvar`. For example, imagine a `Object` instance method, `doSomethingLater`, which uses a weak reference to ensure that it doesn't retain the `Object`, but then has a local strong reference so it can dereference the ivar:

```
- (void)doSomethingLater
{
    __weak Object *weakSelf = self;

    double delayInSeconds = 10.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        Object *strongSelf = weakSelf;
        NSLog(@"%d", strongSelf->_index); // **BAD** - this can crash of `self` has been released by this point
    });
}
```

Thus, you usually replace the above with:

```
- (void)doSomethingLater
{
    __weak Object *weakSelf = self;

    double delayInSeconds = 10.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        Object *strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if (strongSelf) {
            NSLog(@"%d", strongSelf->_index);
        }
    });
}
```

To be perfectly honest, though, the details of why that first code sample can crash and the second can't is less important than the obvious fact that judicious use of your object references in asynchronous programming is important, and failure to handle the situations carefully can result in exceptions. Frequently, checking that the `weakObject` is not `nil` can prevent many of these sorts of issues (with some caveats that I'm not going to go into). This is less important when calling object methods (because sending any message to `nil` results in `nil`), but it is important when your `weakObject` is a parameter or being dereferenced for an ivar.

But to be clear, none of that really has any bearing on thread-safety, though. You achieve thread safety through proper handling of synchronization, such as [locking mechanisms](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1) or through judicious [use of queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW3) (either serial queue; or the reader/writer pattern of a concurrent queue with `dispatch_barrier_async` for writes and `dispatch_sync` for reads).

Just because you have code where you're handling object references carefully so you don't get exceptions, doesn't mean you've achieved thread-safety. There's a whole other layer of concerns that thread-safety entails.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination. The bit of information that I had been missing out is the autoreleasepool and what it is used for. Meanwhile I have done some reading on that and have understood that the object in test2 is released by the autorelease pool (actually putting an autoreleasepool block at the root of test2 and at the root of the dispatch yields the same result as test1). However, what is still a bit of a shady area is understanding why clang ARC is sometimes transforming code to assign/retain and sometimes to autorelease.